# Controling a serial input in an QtGUI with buttons

Tags: python-2.7, qt, user-interface

for my practical project I have to build an GUI around my code. Shortly said:
I'm using an Oxygen-Meter via a serial input. The data string is only sent by the Oxymeter if (of course) the serial port is open and the command "O" is sent. So, for continuous measuring the command has to be sent all the time (with a short break in form of time.sleep(x seconds)). BTW: without a GUI around it everything was working just fine... 
In Qt Designer i made two buttons:
1. Button: should continuously send the command
2. Button: should stop the loop
And here comes an excerpt of the code:

```
    def setupUI(self, DataColOpt):
        ......
        self.Messungstarten = QtGui.QPushButton(self.Datenerfassung)
        self.Messungstarten.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Messungstarten"))
        self.Messungstarten.clicked.connect(self.messung_starten)

    def messung_starten(self):
        while ser1.isOpen():
           ser1.write("O")
           time.sleep(1)
           print "it's working!"

        self.Messungbeenden = QtGui.QPushButton(self.Datenerfassung)
        self.Messungbeenden.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Messungbeenden"))
        self.Messungbeenden.clicked.connect(self.messung_beenden)

    def messung_beenden(self):
        ser1.close()
        print "Ende"
```

If I do it this way and click the "startbutton" the data is collected but the app freezes as soon as i try to click anywhere within the window (e.g. the stop button or the "X" for closing) but the loop continues.
IF I replace the "while" with "if" I'm able to click the other buttons but the datastring is only sent once.
I hope i specified my problem clear enough(besides the fact, that I started coding 2 months ago). Any kind of advice and help is truly appreciated, thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: `messung_starten` is being executed in the same thread as the GUI, so while it's inside the loop it can't process anything GUI-related. Make `messung_starten` a slot, and make the button press emit a **signal** that is connected to this slot.

Comment: I made a mistake with the indentations as I wrote the code example, sorry.